# Trouble with javascript Filter() for validating credit card flag

Tags: angular, typescript

Look, i have a JSON with all the card flags that the establishment accept, looks like this:

```
"CreditCardFlags": [
            {
                "FlagID": "350",
                "FlagName": "Visa"
            },
            {
                "FlagID": "351",
                "FlagName": "Mastercard"
            }
        ],
```

all i want to do is, when the user types its credit card number, the following function is executed:

```js
getCardFlag(cardnumber) {
    var cardnumber = cardnumber.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
    var cards = {
      visa: /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})/,
      mastercard: /^(((51)|(52)|(53)|(54)|(55))\d{0,14})/,
      diners: /^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}/,
      amex: /^3[47][0-9]{13}/,
      discover: /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}/,
      hipercard: /^(606282\d{10}(\d{3})?)|(3841\d{15})/,
      elo: /^((((636368)|(438935)|(504175)|(451416)|(636297))\d{0,10})|((5090)|(5067)|(4576)|(4011))\d{0,12})/,
      jcb: /^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}/,
      aura: /^(5078\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{11})$/
    };
    for (var flag in cards) {
      if (cards[flag].test(cardnumber)) {
        return flag;
      }
    }
  }
```

To get the card flag, but i need to check if the user's credit card flag is one of the flags that the establishment accepts, i transformed the JSON into an object, but how can i do this validation?

Comment: I don't think I am understanding the problem, what's wrong with your code?.

Comment: in the present code you can run a loop over `CreditCardFlags` to return the matched `flag`, however complexity can be improved imo